# Variable referenced before assignment error in prime factorization program?

Tags: python

I am writing some code that is supposed to find the prime factorization of numbers. The main function increments through numbers; I'm doing that because I want to use the code to conduct timing experiments. I don't mind it not being super-efficient, part of the project for me will be making it more efficient myself. It is also not yet totally complete.

```
import math
import time

primfac=[]

def primcheck(n):
    for x in xrange(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primes(n):
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in xrange(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]


def factfind(lsp,n): #finds factors of n among primes
    for i in lsp:
        if n%i==0:
            primfac.append(i)
        else:
            i+=1

def simplify(lsp, n):
    x = 1
    for i in lsp:
        x=i*x
    if x != n:
        print "needs exponent, computing"
        for i in lsp:
            y=n/i
            if primcheck(y) == True:
                lsp.append(y)
            else:
                lsp.append(factfind(primes,y))

def primfacfind(n1,n2):
    while n1 <= n2:
        time_start = time.clock()
        if primcheck(n1) == True:
            print "prime"
            time_elapsed = time.clock() - time_start
            print "time:", time_elapsed
            n1+=1
        else:
            n = n1
            print "starting #", n

            factfind(primes(n),n)
            print primfac

            del primfac
            primfac[:] = []
            simplify(primfac, n)

            time_elapsed = time.clock() - time_start
            print "time:", time_elapsed

            n1+=1

primfacfind(6,15)
```

When I run the code, it gives this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 65, in <module>
  File "python", line 54, in primfacfind
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'primfac' referenced before assignment
```

Which I don't understand because I've tested every function except the `simplify` function and even then the only new part is the lines after `print`.

Comment: The problem is your `del primfac` line in `primefacfind`.  This makes the compiler designate the `primefac` variable as a local variable, but since it doesn't no local variable `primefac` has been created, you get the *runtime error*  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'primfac' referenced before assignment`

Comment: So this is why `print primfac` in the `else` block in `primefacfind` is throwing the error.

Comment: So, for example, I think what you want to achieve instead is `primefac.clear()` instead of `del primefac`, because the latter will cause the compliler to treat `primefac` as a local variable.

Comment: Sorry, in Python 2 you need to use `del primefac[:]` instead of `primefac.clear()`. So basically, if you just leave out `del primfac` your function should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in python can only access variables declared outside of function scope read-only without the global keyword.

```
import math 
import time

primfac=[]

def primcheck(n):
    for x in xrange(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primes(n):
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in xrange(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]


def factfind(lsp,n): #finds factors of n among primes
    for i in lsp:
        if n%i==0:
            primfac.append(i)
        else:
            i+=1

def simplify(lsp, n):
    x = 1
    for i in lsp:
        x=i*x
    if x != n:
        print "needs exponent, computing"
        for i in lsp:
            y=n/i
            if primcheck(y) == True:
                lsp.append(y)
            else:
                lsp.append(factfind(primes,y))

def primfacfind(n1,n2):
    global primfac
    while n1 <= n2:
        time_start = time.clock()
        if primcheck(n1) == True:
            print "prime"
            time_elapsed = time.clock() - time_start
            print "time:", time_elapsed
            n1+=1
        else:
            n = n1
            print "starting #", n

            factfind(primes(n),n)
            print primfac

            del primfac
            primfac = []
            simplify(primfac, n)

            time_elapsed = time.clock() - time_start
            print "time:", time_elapsed

            n1+=1

primfacfind(6,15)
```

Comment: Python can reference variables outside of the function just fine.

Comment: ...but you need the global keyword.  The code I posted, when the "global" keyword is added in the function, avoids the error the OP was having.

Comment: ...as opposed to a majority of other languages, which allow such things without any special treatment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable

Comment: While adding a global keyword fixes the issue *in this specific case*, it's not, in general, necessary to use the global keyword to reference a global variable in Python. Try `x = 'hi'; def f(): print x; f()`

Comment: I was under the impression that, by posting an answer to the OP's question, my answer was supposed to address the issue in the OP's question.

Comment: So, for example, your `global primfac` is useless in `factfind`.

Comment: Yes, *but if your answer implies a generalization that is wrong*, then you should fix that.

Comment: Anyhow, python globals are read-only unless you specify the global keyword, which I would consider to be more cases that "this one weird case"

Comment: Sure, but again, *you can reference them just fine*. Assigning to them automatically assigns to a local variable. If you have an assignment statement anywhere in your function, the compiler treats designates variable as local, which is what causes this runtime error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, your solution worked perfectly; if you post it I will accept it, if not I will accept this answer.